# How do I change the about page on my template to have a full width body/container just as my home page does?

Tags: html, css, shopify

How can I change this container/body to be full width to the edge of the page? Just as the home page is? I have included pictures of the site and extensive bits of the code that may help, I'm fairly new to coding, so I will provide anything I think may be necessary:

[image: Home and About Us]

page.liquid

```
<div id="page" class="desktop-12 tablet-6 mobile-3">
<h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
{{ page.content }}
</div>
```

gridlock.ie.css

```
/* 
 * Gridlock v3.2.1 - 2014-10-28 
 * A responsive CSS grid system. Part of the Formstone Library. 
 * http://formstone.it/gridlock/ 
 * 
 * Copyright 2014 Ben Plum; MIT Licensed 
 */ 

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  *behavior: url(boxsizing.htc);
}
.gridlock .row {
  width: 960px;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-fifth {
  width: 17.91666667%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-fourth {
  width: 22.91666667%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-third {
  width: 31.25%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-half {
  width: 47.91666667%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-full {
  width: 97.91666667%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-push-fifth {
  margin-left: 21.04166667%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-push-fourth {
  margin-left: 26.04166667%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-push-third {
  margin-left: 34.375%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-push-half {
  margin-left: 51.04166667%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-fifth {
  width: 20%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-fourth {
  width: 25%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-third {
  width: 33.33333333%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-half {
  width: 50%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-full {
  width: 100%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-push-fifth {
  margin-left: 20%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-push-fourth {
  margin-left: 25%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-push-third {
  margin-left: 33.33333333%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-push-half {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
.gridlock .row [class*="desktop-"].centered {
  float: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-hide {
  display: none;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-1 {
  width: 6.25%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-2 {
  width: 14.58333333%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-3 {
  width: 22.91666667%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-4 {
  width: 31.25%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-5 {
  width: 39.58333333%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-6 {
  width: 47.91666667%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-7 {
  width: 56.25%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-8 {
  width: 64.58333333%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-9 {
  width: 72.91666667%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-10 {
  width: 81.25%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-11 {
  width: 89.58333333%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-12 {
  width: 97.91666667%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-push-1 {
  margin-left: 9.375%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-push-2 {
  margin-left: 17.70833333%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-push-3 {
  margin-left: 26.04166667%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-push-4 {
  margin-left: 34.375%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-push-5 {
  margin-left: 42.70833333%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-push-6 {
  margin-left: 51.04166667%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-push-7 {
  margin-left: 59.375%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-push-8 {
  margin-left: 67.70833333%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-push-9 {
  margin-left: 76.04166667%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-push-10 {
  margin-left: 84.375%;
}
.gridlock .row .desktop-push-11 {
  margin-left: 92.70833333%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-1 {
  width: 8.33333333%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-2 {
  width: 16.66666667%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-4 {
  width: 33.33333333%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-5 {
  width: 41.66666667%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-7 {
  width: 58.33333333%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-8 {
  width: 66.66666667%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-9 {
  width: 75%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-10 {
  width: 83.33333333%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-11 {
  width: 91.66666667%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-push-1 {
  margin-left: 8.33333333%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-push-2 {
  margin-left: 16.66666667%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-push-3 {
  margin-left: 25%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-push-4 {
  margin-left: 33.33333333%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-push-5 {
  margin-left: 41.66666667%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-push-6 {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-push-7 {
  margin-left: 58.33333333%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-push-8 {
  margin-left: 66.66666667%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-push-9 {
  margin-left: 75%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-push-10 {
  margin-left: 83.33333333%;
}
.gridlock .row .contained.desktop-push-11 {
  margin-left: 91.66666667%;
}
.gridlock .row [class*="all-"].padded,
.gridlock .row [class*="min-"].padded,
.gridlock .row [class*="mobile-"].padded,
.gridlock .row [class*="tablet-"].padded,
.gridlock .row [class*="desktop-"].padded,
.gridlock .row [class*="max-"].padded {
  *behavior: none;
}
```

stylesheet.css

```
/* =============== */
/* = Blogs & Pages = */
/* =============== */

#content h1 { padding-bottom: 5px; margin-bottom: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid {{ settings.dotted_color }}; }
.product #content h1 { margin-bottom: 10px; padding-bottom: 0; border-bottom: 0;  }

.rte h1 {
  border-bottom: 0! important;
  text-align: inherit! important;
  margin-bottom: inherit! important;
}

#page { clear: left; margin-bottom: 50px;   }

#page-sidebar h2 { padding-bottom: 8px; margin-bottom: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid {{ settings.dotted_color }}; }
#page-sidebar ul { list-style-type: none; }
#page-sidebar ul li {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}



.blog .article-index {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid {{ settings.dotted_color }};
}

.blog .article-info h2 { letter-spacing: initial; margin-bottom: 10px; text-align: left; }
.post-tags { clear: left; display: block; text-align: center; }
.blog .article-info p { font-size: {{ settings.font-size }}; }
.blog .article-info a { text-decoration: none! important; text-transform: uppercase; }
.blog .article-content { margin-bottom: 10px; position: relative; }


.article-info ul li.tags {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 12px;
}
ul.tags {
  list-style: none;
}

a.readmore {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px 0 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px 0;
}


.article-modal {
  display: none;
  color: {{ settings.quickview_color }};
  background: {{ settings.quickview_background }}; 
  padding: 0; 
  -webkit-transition: background .5s ease,color .5s ease; 
  -moz-transition: background .5s ease,color .5s ease; 
  -o-transition: background .5s ease,color .5s ease; 
  transition: background .5s ease,color .5s ease;  
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-align: center;
}

.article-modal:hover {  
  color: {{ settings.quickview_color_hover }};
  background: {{ settings.quickview_background_hover }}; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  cursor: pointer;
}

.quick-article { display: none; overflow-y: scroll; }


.article .article-info h2 {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#recent-posts h3 { margin-bottom: 20px; padding-bottom: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid {{ settings.dotted_color }}; }



#instagram-card h3 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#instafeed a {
  line-height: 0;
}


#instafeed a img:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);   
}


#comments h4 { text-align: center; }

#comments { float: left; padding-top: 40px; border-top: 1px solid {{ settings.dotted_color }}; margin-top: 40px; width: 100%; }
#comment-form {  }
ul#commentlist { margin-top: 20px; list-style-type: none; }
ul#commentlist li { float: left; display: block; width: 100%; margin: 0 0 20px 0; border-bottom: 1px solid {{ settings.dotted_color }}; padding-bottom: 20px; }
ul.disc {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.comment-details { margin-bottom: 10px; }
.gravatar { float: left; margin-right: 20px; }
.comment { float: left; }
.comment p { margin-top: 0; }

dd { margin-left: 0; }

.notice { border: 1px dashed #eee; padding: 5px; background: ghostwhite; margin: 20px 0; }


.article .homepage-section {
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: It is best to post actual code here. Not pictures. You are more likely to be helped that way. Try also using https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I have pasted the entire code now, can anyone help me to enter the proper code inside my theme.liquid and stylesheet.css to allow my secondary pages to become full width instead of block style?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try :

```
.yourclass {
    width: 100%;
}
```